# configurar axios con async await en react

Tags: reactjs, async-await

estoy tratando de configurar axios para mi aplicación, mi api recibe peticiones con autorización y sin autorización, en mi aplicación necesito interceptar las solicitudes, si tengo un ítem en el localstorage necesito establecerlo en el header, de lo contrario no hacer nada, tengo este código

```
const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/"
})

Axios.interceptors.request.use(async config => {
   const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token")
   if(token) config.headers = {...config.headers, "Authorization" : token }
   return config
})
```

peroesto no me funciona, cabe aclarar que estoy haciendo la app con expo, gracias por su atencion.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma que me funciona bastante bien es esta

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        const user = localStorage.getItem('user')

        if (user)
            config.headers.Authorization = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).access_token

        return config
    }, (err => {
        return Promise.reject(err)
    }))
}
```

Sólo realizo la validación de si existe el usuario en mi localstorage y de ser así, agregar el correspondiente token junto al request. En caso contrario rechazó la petición!

Comment: esto no funciona bastante bien como dices, me devuelve un error, si prestaste atención a mi pregunta y leíste mi código, te darás cuenta que no estoy usando `localStorage`, sino `AsyncStorage`, que es asíncrono, de modo que en tu código no tiene la palabra clave `await` ni siquiera la función que exporta contiene el `async`.